# Page not refreshing properly

Tags: php

Easy answer fix by the first comment. Sorry page didn't have a redirect now it is fixed and working great.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    require_once("$root/busapp/helpers/session.php");

    if ((isset($sesh_user_id)) || (isset($sesh_admin)) || (isset($sesh_email))) {
         $_SESSION = array();
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_id(), '', time() - 3600);
    }

    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

Comment: you have to redirect the user to login page .

Comment: @aguyfromhere cant for 39 seconds!

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it fixed up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a redirect to the login page when the user logs out.

Try this:

```
<?php

// Some PHP about logging out

header('Location: php/login.php');

?>
```